# Why Does My Emoji Picker ibus Key Combo Fail to Respond in Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, ibus, context-menu, emoji

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> in a native Linux app (e.g., Gedit, TODO, Geary, etc), nothing happens. Why is this, and how can I get a key combo for the default system emoji menu to work?

I have tried setting it to a different key combo with `ibus-setup`. I restart my machine each time I try this, as `ibus exit`, `ibus restart`, `ibus-daemon &` all have no (observable) effect (on this issue).

Every other `ibus-setup` setting will change and respect my settings. Every other key combination I set up in GNOME 3 works just fine. *Only* a key combo assigned to the Emoji picker fails. I can right click Gedit and select the "Insert Emoji" just fine, but grabbing the mouse is a huge flow disruptor .

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 with the latest version of GNOME desktop. I've also verified that I have nothing mapped to any of the key combos I chose, nor the default (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd>).

Can someone help me find the source of this issue, and how I can resolve?

Comment: When you right click on the text entry area, do you see the **Insert Emoji** option?

Comment: Yes, I can right click Gedit and select the "Insert Emoji" just fine.

Comment: I have the same problem. And i can't stand it. Why there is shortcut which i can not disable (ibus-setup emoji shortuc deletion doesn't work for me)...

Answer (score 9):

For me, when I pressed the emoji key combo only 'e' appeared on the text box. Later I found out you're supposed to hit 'space' to bring out the list of categories, or type 'face' + space + space to search for emojis with face on them!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with IBus. See [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IBus#Initial_setup). The following workaround seems to work. In the `~/.xprofile` file (create it if it doesn't already exist), add the following:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=xim
ibus-daemon -xrd
```

Then logout of the current session (or reboot) and log back in. The emoji key combo should be working. If it still doesn't work, change the combination using `ibus-setup`. It will open IBus preferences window. Go to emoji tab, click on the 3 dots `…` button next to 'Emoji annotation', and choose the desired combo. I prefer <Control><Super>e.