# What happened to Ibus Emoji Typing in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, ibus, emoji

In the past few Ubuntu releases (and if my memory serves me right also in 20.04 at the beginning), I was able to insert emoji in every application by clicking <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> and then typing out the name. This is a very convenient feature that suddenly stopped working.

I have already verified that `ibus-daemon` is running and that the keyboard shortcut did not change via `ibus-setup` (I have also tried changing it to something other, but to no avail). I have also attempted the solution described in [this answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1203705/466404), however it only partially solved the issue (the shortcut worked in Gedit but pretty much nowhere else).

Did something change that I missed? Or did I break something on my systems (which would be weird, since it affects both of my machines running 20.04)?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Incidentally, I ran into a fix for this while debugging why my pinyin input was broken. All I had to was add the following to my `~/.profile`:

```bsh
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
ibus-daemon -d -x
```

Sources:

- https://forum.ubuntu.org.cn/viewtopic.php?f=155&t=346639
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IBus#Chinese_input

Comment: Thank you - this solution is similar to the one proposed in the answer I linked above, however it didn’t fully restore functionality when I tried it (only worked in Gedit and possibly other GTK apps), and doesn’t explain why it suddenly stopped working.

Comment: **Update**: nevermind, the subtle differences in your solution seem to have done the trick for me and it seems to work everywhere except in the Gnome-Shell search. I’m still curios if anyone could point out why it suddenly changed (I certainly didn’t modify my `~/.profile` before).

Answer (score 1):

For a simple DConf setting solution that works at least in Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1310815/622358) to a similar question.